# ' Column 'PropertyAddress' in field list is ambiguous' after I run my update statement portion

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, ambiguous

```
SELECT a.ParcelID, a.PropertyAddress, b.ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress, ifnull(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)    
FROM mytable a
join mytable b on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
and a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
where  a.PropertyAddress is null;
```

```
update mytable a
join mytable b on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
and a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
set PropertyAddress = updat
where  a.PropertyAddress is null;
```

**Column 'PropertyAddress' in field list is ambiguous' after I run my update statement portion**

Comment: OK you have property address in 2 tables which one would you like to update? Or both?

Comment: I have updated 'mytable a' by changing set a.PropertyAddress =ifnull(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)    Is it okay?

Comment: and does the statement now behave as desired - if so close the question please.